# Downsizing Image Quality Poor In IE 11 - Fine in Firefox, Chrome, Opera and Safari

Tags: javascript, html, image, internet-explorer

I have an image within a div. The div's width and height is controlled by a third party javascript control "smoothZoom" which works a treat in all browsers except IE. IE8 doesn't render control properly at all (think javascript crashes somewhere) but that's not important right now, it's all IE versions upwards that displays main image badly (pixelated).

The reason for div is we have one main image (layout of building) and several dots (again images) within div side by side with each style "top" and "left" set as coordinates on top of main image.

i.e.:

```
<div>
    <img src="\mainimage.png"/>
    <img style="top: 310px; left: 1675px; width: 50px; height: 50px;" src="/Images/dot.png" data-id="2">
</div>
```

As I said works fine in all browsers except IE with pixelated image and unclear text and thin lines.

EDIT:
I should add the smoothZoom controls the div not the image.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have IE 11 on hand to try this myself, but try setting -ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic in your CSS and see if that has any effect.

EDIT: Looks like this is only supported in IE7. It doesn't appear that IE supports smooth scaling of images anymore.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/e800cbaf-a539-43ba-b5f9-1d29fe709ddc/the-awful-internet-explorer-image-renderengine?forum=ieitprocurrentver